# After module installation, updating translations still at 0%

Tags: i18n-l10n

I installed Drupal 8.5.6, in French. It seemed to work well, apart from no CSS working, but I corrected by unchecking CSS aggregation in the performance settings.

I decided to install some modules, one by one. Every time I install a module, after I click on the *Install* button, I get this.

> [image: screenshot]

After waiting more than 2 minutes (which is abnormal to me), I click on the *Extend* link to see if the module I am trying to install has been installed. The module seems to be installed, since it is checked, but it is not working.

So I uninstall that module, and try installing another module, but I get the same result.

Notice that the first modules I tried installing were the [Coffee](https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/coffee-8.x-1.0-beta2.tar.gz) and [Admin Toolbar](https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/admin_toolbar-8.x-1.24.tar.gz) modules. They get installed properly offline.

I have also noticed that using Drupal 8.2.5 everything is fine.

Is there any version problem, or am I doing something wrong?

I changed the PHP version using on the host to PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 2):

After a few time doing something else, I went back to the issue. In fact a lot of **JavaScript** was not working correctly.

Then I decided to go back to **Configuration -> Performance** and unchecked **JavaScript aggregator** and saved that configuration. See the image below :

[image]

**Now everything works fine**!!!

Now I can use **admin toolbar**'s dropdown menu as well as **coffee** and all the other stuff is working well.

**And thank you for reading me**.

Comment: This is only a work around. The cause of the error is that your Drupal installation is not able to create the aggregated CSS/JS files in sites/default/files/. The same happens for the translation files or the image styles in your follow up question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267401/no-image-is-showing